# How to save files on different mobile devices with and without sd cards?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-sdcard, android-file

I uploaded my app to google play and after this I found that my application has not been working in all devices that i checked except my own...

I believe that the problem is a result of the file save location, I use the following code:

But what happens in devices without SD Card?

in the logcat i recieve error "failed to create directory"

```
    // Step 4: Set output file
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
            .toString());
    outputFileName = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO).toString();





/** Create a File for saving an image or video */
    private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {
        // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
        // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.



    File mediaStorageDir = new File(
            Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES),
            "Your_voice");
    // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
    // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.d("Your_voice_App", "failed to create directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyy_HHmmss")
            .format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "Your_voice" + timeStamp + ".mp4");
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can then review, edit and quickly share them without needing to boot up your PC. It'll also allow you to watch videos stored on the card, meaning you don't need to clog up your precious internal storage with huge video files.

http://resultplanet.org/